# What benefits does the average citizen gain from the US being "number one?"

Tags: international-relations, china, power

It's often said by politicians on the left and right that America needs to be on top of the world order, and that the rise of China is an existential threat to the American position atop the world order; thus America needs to outcompete China.

But what's in it for the average Joe? How is his life different if China has the largest GDP or if America has the largest GDP? As long as the People's Liberation Army isn't attacking the US mainland (an extremely unlikely scenario) how does he benefit from America having a stronger military than China? If Europe falls under Chinese influence due to the belt and road initiative, does it meaningfully impact the life of the average American? If China takes over the South China Sea, does it impact the average American?

One idea I have seen is that since the dollar is the global reserve currency, the US can print money at leisure for its own use and not create significant amounts of inflation. I don't know if this is true.

Comment: What politician wouldn't want to have their country be "number one"? Everyone is going to have a different reason for wanting to be "number one".

Comment: Is there an objective way to measure being number one?

Answer (score 6):

We are living in a globalized economy. The rules of this economy are getting negotiated (or wrestled) between governments and other economic actors, and being the nation which sets the "blueprint" of the world order gives a distinct advantage to that nation, and indirectly to the citizens.

- Americans traveling abroad can usually find someone speaking English. Two centuries ago, it was French. Who knows, it might be Chinese two centuries from now.
- Americans trading abroad can understand the legal system, mostly. Easier with the UK or Canada than with the EU, but still there are many similarities.
- Foreign companies are willing to produce parts consistent with American standards (safety, environmental, and just plain arbitrary). What if the standards came from China, and American companies had to adapt to them to export?